# error running JUNIT tests in spring using @ContextConfiguration

Tags: junit, spring-integration

I have this strange error running junit tests and have not been able to find a cause for this. Strangely this works fine in the **local eclipse** but not on the **build server**.
Any clue would be highly appreciated, thanks

I am using `@ContextConfiguration(...)` and which is auto-wired

```
13:42:30.372 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7f4e0ba] to prepare test instance [com.abc.wss.bes.portal.integration.TestCommon@34330fb9]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

This is the innermost caused by -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [class java.lang.Void] for method match: [public static int[] com.abc.wss.bes.portal.integration.data.portal.DataTransformer.__cobertura_get_and_reset_counters(), public static void com.abc.wss.bes.portal.integration.data.portal.DataTransformer.__cobertura_classmap_0(com.coverity.capture.cobertura.coveragedata.LightClassmapListener)]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:89) ~[spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:429) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:186) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:136) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:131) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:57) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MethodInvokingTransformer.<init>(MethodInvokingTransformer.java:47) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.TransformerFactoryBean.createMethodInvokingHandler(TransformerFactoryBean.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandler(AbstractStandardMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.createHandlerInternal(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:113) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.getObject(AbstractSimpleMessageHandlerFactoryBean.java:43) ~[spring-integration-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:144) ~[spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Show the code of your `DataTransformer`, first of all. And how you use it from Spring Integration.
It is strange that `MessagingMethodInvokerHelper` points out to static methods...

Comment: 'public class DataTransformer {
 private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataTransformer.class);
 
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public Object transform(Message<?> message)
 {
  Object payload = message.getPayload();
  // process and replace payload
  return message;   
 }

}'  ----- It is just pojo, does not look like problem is here, i have this problem only when a build is using cobertura

Comment: In have this spring integration process that i am trying to test, i am loading my configuration using @ContextConfiguration...after that i intend to use various components defined and do some test on them.

Comment: But its defiantly linked to DataTransformer class and also another similar class, i removed these 2 SI workflow from my application context and it seem to build fine. Not sure why a pojo is undesirable to this build.

Comment: alas, it turns out that me using  a pojo  (instead of extends AbstractTransformer) was the problem for the build, not sure why,  The SI seems to happy though with a POJO and was working fine.